# Django not translated in Heroku while in development it is

Tags: heroku, translation, gitignore, django-i18n

I had Django 1.5.5 translation working correctly in development but when deployed to Heroku strings were not being translated.

Answer (score 3):

The reason was that I had `*.mo` in my global `.gitignore` and so I added `!*.mo` to the local `.gitignore` to solve it.